# How can I pass multiline String parameter?

Tags: ruby, string

Let's say that I have this method:

```
def read_line_by_line(some_text)
  some_text.each |line| do (something) end
end
```

How can I do that? I had:

```
my first line
of the input text
```

and I tried to pass it as parameter, and I got a strange output. It doesn't read it line by line.

Comment: "Strange output" tells us nothing. We need to see what you saw, so we have to be able to duplicate the problem. Your method would work with Ruby 1.8.7 but won't work with newer Rubies because `each` is no longer a String method. `each_line` replaced it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying:

```
def read_line_by_line(some_text)
  some_text.each_line {|line| puts line }
end

str = <<-eot
my first line
of the input text
eot

read_line_by_line(str)
# >> my first line
# >> of the input text
```

See the documentation of [**`String#each_line`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-each_line).

**Update**

```
def read_line_by_line(some_text)
  some_text.each_line {|line| puts line }
end

str = "my first line\nof the input text"

read_line_by_line(str)
# >> my first line
# >> of the input text
```

For creating multiple-line strings, Ruby supports [***`Here documents`***](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents).

Comment: is this the way I have to pass it if it is a multiline?with eot?
You say that it is imposible just to copy/paste it in the method parameters?

Comment: This is called *Heredoc*.

Comment: Sorry for being that lame but I am newbie in Ruby and I come from the .net world and I still can not get used to the Ruby semantics.I just wanted to ask you if this is the one and only way to pass multiline string to method parameter?

if I had 
"my first line \n
 my second line "

and I tried to copy/paste it in the -> method_name(parameter)
it would work if it was not with the eot ?

Comment: @user2128702 See now...

Comment: Using a here-doc has nothing to do with a solution, it's just one way of creating sample text with embedded line-feeds. Ruby is no different than other languages when dealing with text and line-endings. The line-end characters are just characters, like the rest, they're just not visible.

Comment: @theTinMan I use Heredoc while I deal with multiline strings.. So I told OP the same,I also linked one link for the same...

Comment: The comment was to the OP who was confused by the here-doc, thinking it was necessary when using embedded new-lines and that it was Ruby-specific.

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry! I misunderstood you.. :) May be you should place @_opname... in the comment.. I didn't understand to whom you addressed..